# Risk involved with using PPA from old release?

Tags: ppa, updates

I have some PPA's in my update sources that don't maintain active builds for oneiric. Is it safe to continue receiving updates from these PPA's using builds for prior releases like Natty or Maverick? Thanks.

Comment: we can perhaps give you a better answer if you list the PPAs in your question.

Comment: If a PPA has no Oneiric, you most likely not receive any updates from it. PPAs usually have different packages for different releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general installing a package from a different distribution isn't recommended as explained in the [pinning how to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) wiki page.

However, you can still try to:

- Fetch the source package
- Generate the binary packages in your machine
- Install them using `dpkg -i`.

If your sources are correctly configured this this can be done with:

```
$ apt-get source --compile <source_package>
$ dpkg -i <binary_packages>
```

All this is explained in the [recommended alternative to pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Recommended_alternative_to_pinning) section in the how to. Please note, that the assumption of the how to is that you try to install packages from a new distribution in an old one, not the other way around; but I think most of the contents there is still valid to your case.

Finally, for some particular cases, like applications that don't try to modify your system, written in an interpreted language, then probably you're safe to install the software directly from the PPA.